# How to calculate dynamic panel models with lfe package

Tags: r, xts, plm, lfe

I am trying to estimate a large dynamic fixed effects panel data model with lags, and multiple group effects.

I know about the `pseries` object from the `plm` package which can handle panel regression with lags.

```
library(plm)
data("EmplUK", package = "plm")
Em <- pdata.frame(EmplUK)
plm(emp~output+capital + lag(wage, 1),data=Em,model="within")
```

Is there a similar solution in the `lfe` package for panel objects so that I can take advantage of the speediness that `lfe` provides?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no direct way to do lags in `felm` as of now, but it is possible to do it as follows:

```
library(lfe)
felm(emp~output+capital + lag(Em[,'wage'],1)|firm,data=Em)
```

The reason the lag does not work straight away with `felm` is that it will use the default lag function, not the `pseries` lag. When specifying it as above, the `pseries` lag is used.

Another way to make it work is:

```
felm(emp~output+capital + lag(wage,1)|firm,data=as.data.frame(Em))
```

I.e. include an explicit `as.data.frame`, this will convert `Em` to a `"data.frame"` with appropriate attributes. This will incur a copy of the entire dataset, but is no different from what **plm** does behind the scene.

Comment: The next release of lfe (in a month or so) will support this directly with pseries, provided plm is loaded. It turned out to be a very simple fix. At a single point when I create the model frame, I have replaced an "as.formula" with an "as.Formula". The class of 'wage' is then preserved, and the right lag() will be used.

Comment: The current version of lfe (2.3) handles this, i.e. `felm(emp~output+capital + lag(wage, 1)|firm,data=Em)` will use the pseries lag.